# Fetch Non-existent ancestor documents-Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get non-existent ancestor documents in Firestore. Can someone help me?
This is the code that I am using to fetch documents.

```
void fetchAllDocuments() async {
  try {
    QuerySnapshot allDocs = await _firestore.collection("chatroom").get();

    print("Total Documents: ${allDocs.docs.length}");

    if (allDocs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      for (QueryDocumentSnapshot docSnapshot in allDocs.docs) {
        print("Document Id: " + docSnapshot.id);
        Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        print("Document Data: " + data.toString());
      }
    } else {
      print("No documents found in the collection.");
    }

    setState(() {
      // You can add any necessary state updates here
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error fetching documents: $e");
  }
}
```

The collection name is 'chatroom'. This is the SS of Firestore.

[image: SS of Firestore]

By using this code, I can only get the documents that are auto-generated. But I can't fetch the documents that are manually generated with code. If I give the document id then I can get the document that is generated manually. But I want to get all documents that are generated manually without giving the document ID.

There are currently 5 documents in the collection, but I can get only 3. The output of this code is:

> I/flutter (22391): Total Documents: 3
> I/flutter (22391): Document Id: eDcHItpnzg1YeGccCmEy
> I/flutter (22391): Document Data: {}
> I/flutter (22391): Document Id: paEMIb4olR0UjqK31AiZ
> I/flutter (22391): Document Data: {}
> I/flutter (22391): Document Id: vsJc5BkQEXgYyRI8lKgh
> I/flutter (22391): Document Data: {}

By using the below code, I am generating the documents manually.

```
ListTile(
  onTap: () {
    String roomId = chatRoomId(
        _auth.currentUser!.displayName!,
        userMap!['name']);

    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => ChatRoom(
          chatRoomId: roomId,
          userMap: userMap!,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  leading: Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Colors.black),
  title: Text(
    userMap!['name'],
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 17,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    ),
  ),
  subtitle: Text(userMap!['email']),
  trailing: Icon(Icons.chat, color: Colors.black),
)

String chatRoomId(String user1, String user2) {
  if (user1[0].toLowerCase().codeUnits[0] >
      user2.toLowerCase().codeUnits[0]) {
    //If user 1 send message to user 2.
    // return "$user1$user2";
    return "abc";
  } else {
    //If user 2 send message to user 1.
    // return "$user2$user1";
    return "def";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are currently 5 documents in the collection, but I can get only 3.

No, there are only three documents in the collection and **not** 5. The first two, which are written in *italics*, are present there because there is a sub-collection (chats) present under it. But those documents don't exist. You see those document IDs so you can navigate further into the sub-collections.

One thing to remember, in Cloud Firestore documents and sub-collections don't work like filesystem files and directories in your computer. If you create a sub-collection under a document, it doesn't implicitly create any parent document. Sub-collections are not tied in any way to a parent document.

If you want to get 5 documents, then you should add a field of any type inside the document or at least a field with a `null` value.

Comment: Hey Hamza. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the code please.

Comment: There is no need to write code in order to add a field in a Firestore document. You can do that right in the console. Give it a try and tell me if it works.